# Node.js my function showing undefined dictionary value despite assigning it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to javascript so i'm sorry if this has been asked before.

I have this function which i use to read json files.

```
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

function readData(fileName: string, callback) {
jsonfile.readFile(".\\data\\" + fileName + ".json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    callback(null, data);
 })
}
```

Then I call it using this:

```
// Read JSON files
var fileList = ["guides"];
var files = {};

for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    readData(fileList[i], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        files[i] = result;
    })
}
```

but when I:

```
console.log(files['guides']);
```

it returns `undefined`. Can anyone help me fix this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Reason why you get undefined is because most likely you are logging `files['guides']` _before_ `files` object is populated and that is because it is populated _asynchronously_ and the asynchronous code is executed _after_ the synchronous code which includes you console.log statement as well.

Comment: @Yousaf no offence but reading your comment makes my head spin. Could you like...rephrase it and make it easier to read?

Comment: @Capt171 none taken. Hopefully the answer below makes it easier to understand the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callback function of the `jsonfile.readFile` function is called *asynchronously* and your `console.log` statement is executed synchronously.

Asynchronous code is executed *after* the synchronous execution of your javascript code has ended; as a result, your `console.log` statement is logging `files['guides']` *before* `guides` property is added in the `files` object. This is why you get undefined.

Following code example shows this problem in action:

```js
let a = 1;

setTimeout(() => {
  a = 2; 
}, 100);

console.log(a);
```

Above code snippet outputs `1` because the callback function of `setTimeout` is invoked *asynchronously*, i.e. *after* the `console.log(a)` statement has been executed and at the time of execution of `console.log` statement, value of `a` is `1`.

**Solution**

To make sure that you log `files["guides"]` *after* all the files have been read and `files` object has been populated, you could return a promise from the `readData` function.

Following code shows how you could create a promise wrapper around `readData` function:

```
function readData(fileName) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      jsonfile.readFile(".\\data\\" + fileName + ".json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
         if (err) reject(err);
         else resolve(data);
      })
   }
};
```

Now you can call the above function as:

```
Promise.all(fileList.map(filePath => readData(filePath)))
  .then(dataFromAllFiles => {
     console.log(dataFromAllFiles);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

**Useful Links:**

- [Asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)
- [Graceful asynchronous programming with Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises)
- [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: Definitely clearer!